# Why is this recursive function returning undefined values?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator in Vanilla js that can evaluate `BODMAS` expressions. Here is the code:
index.js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    displayInput();
    displayResult();
})

function displayInput() {
    let valueButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.calculator-button');
    valueButtons.forEach(valueButton => {
        let value = valueButton.innerHTML;
        valueButton.onclick = function() {
            document.querySelector('#calculator-input').value += value;
        }
    })
}

function isOperator(opr) {
    if (opr === '+' || opr === '-' || opr === 'x' || opr === '/') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function displayResult() {
    let expression = '', result = '';
    document.querySelector('#calculator-calculate').onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        expression = document.querySelector('#calculator-input').value;
        result = getResult(expression);
        document.querySelector('.calculator-result').innerHTML = result;
    }
}

function updateExpression(index, expr) {
    let o1 = '', o2 = '';
    let start = 0, end = expr.length-1, flag = 0;
    for (let i = index-1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (!isOperator(expr[i])) {
            o1 += expr[i];
        }
        else {
            start = i+1;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (let i = index+1; i < expr.length; i++) {
        if (!isOperator(expr[i])) {
            o2 += expr[i];
        }
        else {
            end = i-1;
            break;
        }
    }

    let opr1 = parseInt(o1.split('').reverse().join('')), opr2 = parseInt(o2), result = 0;
    if (expr[index] === '+') {
        result = opr1+opr2;
    }
    if (expr[index] === '-') {
        result = opr1-opr2;
    }
    if (expr[index] === 'x') {
        result = opr1*opr2;
    }
    if (expr[index] === '/') {
        result = opr1/opr2;
    }

    if (start == 0) {
        if (end == expr.length-1) {
            return `${result}`;
        }
        else {
            return `${result}`+expr.substr(end+1,);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (end == expr.length-1) {
            return expr.substr(0, start)+`${result}`;
        }
        else {
            
            //alert(expr.substr(end+1,));
            return expr.substr(0, start)+`${result}`+expr.substr(end+1,);
        }
    }
}

function getResult(expr) {
    let first = expr.lastIndexOf('('), last = expr.indexOf(')'), flag = 0;
    alert("first = "+first+", last = "+last+", expr = "+expr);
    if (first == -1 || last == -1) {
        return evaluate(expr);
    }
    for (let i = first+1; i < last; i++) {
        if (isOperator(expr[i])) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        expr = expr.substr(0, first)+`${evaluate(`${expr.substr(first+1, last)}`)}`+expr.substr(last+1,);
    }
    getResult(expr);
}

function evaluate(expr) {
    while (expr.search('/') != -1) {
        expr = updateExpression(expr.search('/'), expr);
    }
    while (expr.search('x') != -1) {
        expr = updateExpression(expr.search('x'), expr);
    }
    while (expr.indexOf('+') != -1) {
        expr = updateExpression(expr.indexOf('+'), expr);
    }
    while (expr.search('-') != -1) {
        expr = updateExpression(expr.search('-'), expr);
    }
    return expr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JavaScipt Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///A:/js%20projects/calculator/index.css">
    <script src="file:///A:/js%20projects/calculator/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator-form">
        
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter expression" id="calculator-input"> <br>
        <div class="calculator-buttons">
            <button class="calculator-button">1</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">2</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">3</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">+</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="calculator-buttons">
            <button class="calculator-button">4</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">5</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">6</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">x</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">/</button>
        </div>
        <div class="calculator-buttons">
            <button class="calculator-button">7</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">8</button>
            <button class="calculator-button">9</button>
            <button class="calculator-button" id="delete-char">⌫</button>
        </div>
        <div class="calculator-buttons">
            <button class="calculator-button">0</button>
            <button type="submit" id="calculator-calculate">=</button>
        </div>
        <div class="calculator-result">
            No result yet!
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I input `((12+3)+7)`, I can see that the correct calculation is being done through alerts. But the actual result is `undefined`:
**First alert**
[image]

**Second alert**. Problem starts from here: `expRem` should be `12+3` instead of `12+3)+`.
[image]

**Third alert**
[image]

........

**Last alert**
[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: You didn't `return getResult(expr);`

Comment: @James the result remains the same!

Comment: Please update your question with the html needed to make the snippet reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I think I see the problem.  You are using `expr.substr(first+1, last)` which takes a starting index and a length.  I think you want to use `expr.substring(first+1, last)` which takes a starting index and an ending index.